# Java get() function doesn't work

Tags: java

so I'm learning JAVA by myself and I have only the basic knowledge about programming languages in general. I wrote this simple calculator program to try and apply what I've been learning this far, but the problem is that it doesn't print the age, instead it prints a 0 and I don't know why:

this is the class

```
public class userinput {

private String name;
private int age;

public tuna (String name, int age){
    name = "dina";
    age = 3;
}

public void simpleMessage2(){
    System.out.println("hello " + name + " ready to use our calculator?");
}

public void setName(String Uname){
    name = Uname;
}

public void setAge(int uage){
    uage = age;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public int getAge(){
    return age;
}

public void printname(){
    System.out.printf("your name is %s", getName());
    System.out.println();
}

public void printage(){
    System.out.println("your age is");
    System.out.println(getAge());
    System.out.println();
}}
```

and this is the main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class calc {
public static void main (String args[]) {

    String name1;
    int age1;

    Scanner bucky = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice, num1, num2, sum;

    System.out.println("Hey, enter your name");
    name1 = bucky.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Hey, enter your age");
    age1 = bucky.nextInt();

    tuna objc1 = new userinput(name1, age1);

    objc1.setName(name1);
    objc1.printname();
    System.out.println();

    objc1.setAge(age1);
    objc1.printage();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("this is a basic calculator, select from the menu:");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for summation");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 for subtraction");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 for multiplication");
    System.out.println("Enter 4 for division");
    System.out.println("Enter 5 for module");
    System.out.println("Enter 0 to exit");

    choice = bucky.nextInt();

    while (choice != 0) {   

        switch(choice){

        case 1:
            System.out.println("enter the 1st num");
            num1 = bucky.nextInt();
            System.out.println("enter the 2nd num");
            num2 = bucky.nextInt();
            System.out.println("the sum is equal to: ");
            sum = num1 + num2;
            System.out.print(sum);
            System.out.println("Select another operation from the menu or enter 0 to exit");
            choice = bucky.nextInt();
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("enter the 1st num");
            num1 = bucky.nextInt();
            System.out.println("enter the 2nd num");
            num2 = bucky.nextInt();
            System.out.println("the sub is equal to: ");
            sum = num1 - num2;
            System.out.print(sum);
            System.out.println("Select another operation from the menu or enter 0 to exit");
            choice = bucky.nextInt();
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("enter the 1st num");
            num1 = bucky.nextInt();
            System.out.println("enter the 2nd num");
            num2 = bucky.nextInt();
            System.out.println("the mul is equal to: ");
            sum = num1 * num2;
            System.out.print(sum);
            System.out.println("Select another operation from the menu or enter 0 to exit");
            choice = bucky.nextInt();
            break;

        case 4:
            System.out.println("enter the 1st num");
            num1 = bucky.nextInt();
            System.out.println("enter the 2nd num");
            num2 = bucky.nextInt();
            System.out.println("the div is equal to: ");
            sum = num1 / num2;
            System.out.print(sum);
            System.out.println("Select another operation from the menu or enter 0 to exit");
            choice = bucky.nextInt();
            break;

        case 5:
            System.out.println("enter the 1st num");
            num1 = bucky.nextInt();
            System.out.println("enter the 2nd num");
            num2 = bucky.nextInt();
            System.out.println("the mod is equal to: ");
            sum = num1 % num2;
            System.out.print(sum);
            System.out.println("Select another operation from the menu or enter 0 to exit");
            choice = bucky.nextInt();
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid entry, please try again");
            choice = bucky.nextInt();
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("Bye!");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You forget `sql` and `javascript` tags.

Comment: why in god's name have you tagged c# and c for a java question?

Comment: I don't think your code can compile. Why not show us a compliable code and tell us your exact input, expected and actual output you are getting. You are having a class named `userInput` with a `tuna` constructor.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. At the moment, you've posted 150 lines of code - chances are 95% of that code is irrelevant. You should narrow the problem down to a [mcve]. In the course of doing that, you may well find the problem yourself.

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Where is the tuna class?

```
tuna objc1 = new userinput(name1, age1);
```

the userinput's Constructor:

```
public userinput(String n, int a){
    name = n;
    age = a;
}
```

I was just learning

Answer (score 0):

the first error you don't have tuna class change the error to

```
tuna objc1 = new userinput(name1,age1);
```

to

```
userinput objc1 = new userinput();
```

then i change your code like that the method you use it in first class 
and the second class to make operation 
**the first class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class userinput {

private  String name;
private int age;

public void simpleMessage2(){
    System.out.println("hello " + name + " ready to use our calculator?");
}

public void setName(String Uname){
    name = Uname;
}

public void setAge(int uage){
        age= uage;    }
public void printname(){
    System.out.printf("your name is %s", getName());
    System.out.println();
}
public void printage(){
System.out.printf("your age is %s", getAge());
    System.out.println();}
public int getAge(){
    return age;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
}
```

**the second class**

```
class calc {
public static void main (String args[]) {

    String name1;
    int age1;

    Scanner bucky = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice, num1, num2, sum;

    System.out.println("Hey, enter your name");
    name1 = bucky.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Hey, enter your age");
    age1 = bucky.nextInt();

    userinput objc1 = new userinput();

    objc1.setName(name1);
    objc1.printname();
    System.out.println();

    objc1.setAge(age1);
    objc1.printage();
    System.out.println();
    objc1.simpleMessage2();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("this is a basic calculator, select from the menu:");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for summation");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 for subtraction");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 for multiplication");
    System.out.println("Enter 4 for division");
    System.out.println("Enter 5 for module");
    System.out.println("Enter 0 to exit");

    choice = bucky.nextInt();

    while (choice != 0) {   

        switch(choice){

        case 1:
            System.out.println("enter the 1st num");
            num1 = bucky.nextInt();
            System.out.println("enter the 2nd num");
            num2 = bucky.nextInt();
            System.out.println("the sum is equal to: ");
            sum = num1 + num2;
            System.out.println(sum);
            System.out.println("Select another operation from the menu or enter 0 to exit");
            choice = bucky.nextInt();
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("enter the 1st num");
            num1 = bucky.nextInt();
            System.out.println("enter the 2nd num");
            num2 = bucky.nextInt();
            System.out.println("the sub is equal to: ");
            sum = num1 - num2;
            System.out.println(sum);
            System.out.println("Select another operation from the menu or enter 0 to exit");
            choice = bucky.nextInt();
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("enter the 1st num");
            num1 = bucky.nextInt();
            System.out.println("enter the 2nd num");
            num2 = bucky.nextInt();
            System.out.println("the mul is equal to: ");
            sum = num1 * num2;
            System.out.println(sum);
            System.out.println("Select another operation from the menu or enter 0 to exit");
            choice = bucky.nextInt();
            break;

        case 4:
            System.out.println("enter the 1st num");
            num1 = bucky.nextInt();
            System.out.println("enter the 2nd num");
            num2 = bucky.nextInt();
            System.out.println("the div is equal to: ");
            sum = num1 / num2;
            System.out.println(sum);
            System.out.println("Select another operation from the menu or enter 0 to exit");
            choice = bucky.nextInt();
            break;

        case 5:
            System.out.println("enter the 1st num");
            num1 = bucky.nextInt();
            System.out.println("enter the 2nd num");
            num2 = bucky.nextInt();
            System.out.println("the mod is equal to: ");
            sum = num1 % num2;
            System.out.println(sum);
            System.out.println("Select another operation from the menu or enter 0 to exit");
            choice = bucky.nextInt();
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid entry, please try again");
            choice = bucky.nextInt();
            break;
        }


    }
    System.out.println("Bye!");}


}
```

**I hope i help you**